# split a variable in unix shell script with dot delimiter

Tags: shell, unix

I am trying following.

```
echo $FCMAN |cut -d'.' -f1 | read FCMAN1
echo $FCMAN |cut -d'.' -f2 | read FCMAN2
echo $FCMAN |cut -d'.' -f3 | read FCMAN3
echo $FCMAN |cut -d'.' -f4 | read FCMAN4
```

`$FCMAN` has value shown below.

```
QLogic Corp. QLogic Corp. QLogic Corp. QLogic Corp.
```

And I expect following four variables as a result.

```
$FCMAN1 = QLogic Corp.
$FCMAN2 = QLogic Corp.
$FCMAN3 = QLogic Corp.
$FCMAN4 = QLogic Corp.
```

Could someone help me out with it?

Comment: What do you want to happen to the spaces around each `.`? Which shell are you using? Perhaps you could consider an array rather than these numbered variables. Some explanation of what you're trying to do with these variables would also be useful.

Comment: I am collecting fiber channel adapter information like (manufacturer, model number etc.) from a central management system which can run script remotely on all the type of servers.

command I ma using is give me result in one line regardless of number of adapters. maximum number of adapter we have is 4.

later I want to feed this info to DB and that is the reason i need to split them.

script will be executed on Solaris (x86 or SPARC), LINUX or HPUX so can have different shell.

Hope this explains.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use an array instead. The `mapfile` bash builtin reads lines into an array:

```sh
FCMAN="QLogic Corp. QLogic Corp. QLogic Corp. QLogic Corp."
mapfile -t fcmen < <( tr . '\n' <<<"$FCMAN")
declare -p fcmen
# ==> declare -a fcmen='([0]="QLogic Corp" [1]=" QLogic Corp" [2]=" QLogic Corp" [3]=" QLogic Corp" [4]="")'
```

Comment: This loses the `.` and it's not clear that the OP is using bash.

Comment: the script will run on all type of UNIX (Solaris,HPUX and LINUX) so i dont want to rely on something which works only with bash.

Comment: @rora: Is there an OS without bash? I could understand if you don't want to depend on features in new bash versions, but even bash version 3 is now already more than 10 years old....

Comment: i meant korn shell or may be some OS use something else. and if there is no os without bash then why people are asking? i.e "it's not clear that the OP is using bash"

Answer (score 0):

You say that your script should run on *all* types of Unix; so, what shell (or other tool) do you expect to be available everywhere? Even if you count on `sh` (Bourne Shell), it will be different: On Linux, `sh` simply calls `bash`, and although there is supposed to be an upward compatibility, not every Bourne shell script produces the same result when executed under bash, as [this article](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sh.html) demonstrates.

With Korn Shell, differences are even bigger - different implementations, different versions of one implementation line. Some setups might not even have Korn Shell installed in /usr/bin.

If you are happy with the result of your original code, you could make it a bit more elegant by using a loop:

```
for n in 1 2 3 4
do
    echo $FCMAN|cut -d'.' -f$n|read FCMAN$n
done
```

Another possibility would be to use `Perl`. While not necessarily part of *every* Unix installation, I have yet to see one where Perl is not installed. Although you have many different Perl versions around, it will for sure be some 5.xx version, and your case is simple enough to write it in a way that it will work with any Perl version.

Comment: Problem is there is no result from my original code so using a loop will not help me too.

Comment: But setting FCMAN to the string you posted, *will* give the desired result. The same with your original code.

Comment: FCMAN has velue "QLogic Corp. QLogic Corp. QLogic Corp. QLogic Corp." in it but FCMAN1/2/3/4 are empty.

Comment: Using **which** shell?

Comment: I didn't mean that you should use the "which" command, and both information doesn't say which shell you have actually used to run your shell. Since you are writing the script, you for sure should know, what shell language you are using. Either you invoke the script by stating a shell explicitly on the command line, or you have a shee-bang-line which names the shell.